# Is a finite set in R² open?

Tags: metric-spaces

How can a finite set E in R² not be open? Isn't every point of E an interior point of E (since the point will be contained in its own neighbourhood)? And if every point in E is an interior point, then every point in E is also interior in R², since E is a finite subset of R². Then, E should be open in R².

Comment: You might want to look up the definition of "neighborhood".  A neighborhood has to be a union of open disks.

Comment: A point $x$ is in the interior of $E$ if you can find a small enough ball centered at $x$ which lies entirely in E. For a non-empty finite set, you cannot find such balls.

Comment: Your tag "metric spaces" implies that you are using a metric topology. If this is so, then please make it explicit. What is open and what is closed is determined by the topology alone.

Comment: Actually, I must disagree with @Joe here: A neightbourhood of a point must contain an open disk centered at that point, but that does not make it a union of open disks. For a simple counterexample, take a closed disk of positive radius centered at the point in question.

Comment: Set $E$ is open in $E$ for the reason you state in your first question.  If we just say $E$ is open, however, we would mean $E$ is open in $\mathbb R^2$.  That is false in this case, so your assertion "every point in $E$ is also interior in $\mathbb R^2$" is false.

Answer (score 1):

A finite set is never open, because it  cannot contain any open balls (so therefore can't be a union of them).

Comment: Some triviality: A non-empty finite set...

Comment: @Parul : In case you don't understand Ustun's comment, the empty set is finite, open, and closed.  This may seem trivial, but it means a finite set in your problem actually can be open.